# $\nabla \frac{1}{|x|}$ is Lipschitz continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^3.$
How to prove $\nabla \frac{1}{|x|}$ is Lipschitz continuous for $|x|\geq1$?

I tried that WLOG suppose $|y|\geq |x|$, then

$$ \left| \frac{x}{|x|^3} - \frac{y}{|y|^3} \right| =  \frac{1}{|x|^3} \left| x - \frac{|x|^3}{|y|^3}y \right| \leq C(?)|x-y|$$

I don't know how to construct $C$.

Comment: its smooth, on an open set containing $|x|\ge1$, and decays at infinity

Comment: What's the absolute value of a vector in $\mathbf R^3$??

Comment: @Bernard I don’t know if you are trying to be Socratic but that’s the Euclidean norm

Comment: That's not the usual notation…

Comment: You can try to apply the *Mean Value inequality* for multivariable functions.

Comment: @Bernard this notation is extremely standard in many subfields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{x|y|^3-y|x|^3}{|x|^3|y|^3}=\frac{(x-y)|y|^3}{|x|^3|y|^3}+\frac{y(|y|^3-|x|^3)}{|x|^3|y|^3}.$$Now factor the numerator in the second fraction on the right and note that $\left||y|-|x|\right|\le|x-y|.$

Answer (score 1):

You can just try to be a bit more explicit and compute the square norm:

$$\left|\dfrac{x}{|x|^3} - \dfrac{y}{|y|^3}\right|^2 = \dfrac{(x^T|y|^3 - y^T|x|^3)(x|y|^3 - y|x|^3)}{|x|^6|y|^6} = \dfrac{|x|^4+|y|^4 - 2|x||y|x^Ty}{|x|^4|y|^4}.$$

Now use Cauchy-Schwarz as:
$$x^Ty\leq |x||y|$$
then you are basically done.